# Relatve URL in distant file (XLS)

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, webserver, relative-path, relative-url

I have a problem at my job.

I am totally dependent on a website which must certainly date from the eighties ...
In one of the web pages, there is a link to download an excel file (xls). Let's say for example http://example.excel.xls
In this file, there are hyperlinks to other files (sometimes i think the death penalty is a good thing! ^^).
These links are relative :'( (for example \myfile.pdf)

Internet explorer, strangely, are correcting these links by transforming them in absolute path (http://example.myfile.pdf)
Other browsers (chrome, firefox, even the old edge) don't do it natively. By clicking on the link, we arrive in the local cache, where of course there arenot my files ...
I will soon have to remove IE from computers.

I had considered sending a bombshell on the administrators of this website, but afraid of legal repercussions :)

Is it possible, via settings, an addon or whatever, to make one of the browsers behave in the same way as IE?

I am very grateful for the help you will give me

Answer (score 0):

You had asked,"`Is it possible, via settings, an addon or whatever, to make one of the browsers behave in the same way as IE?`"

I suggest you make a test with the [MS Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge) (Chromium) browser.

The MS Edge (Chromium) browser comes with the [IE mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode) feature.

IE mode on Microsoft Edge makes it easy to use all of the sites your organization needs in a single browser. It uses the integrated Chromium engine for modern sites, and it uses the Trident MSHTML engine from Internet Explorer 11 (IE11) for legacy sites.

To configure IE mode, I suggest you refer to [Configure IE mode policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies). You can refer to the document and configure the necessary policies to enable the IE mode.

It can help you to load your legacy site in the Edge browser using the IE mode which can help you to fix the said issue.